# LDAP Query Of All Users In Various Groups In A Specific ActiveDirectory OU

Tags: active-directory, ldap, query

I need to configure Atlassian Crowd to query all the users in my AD server that are in various groups in a top-level OU.

The DN for the OU is "OU=Atlassian,DC=NNNN,DC=com". The various groups would be "CN=,OU=Atlassian,DC=NNNN,DC=com". There are 30.

I have used:

```
(&(objectCategory=Person)(sAMAccountName=*)
  (|
    (memberOf=CN=group1,OU=Atlassian,DC=NNNN,DC=com)
    (memberOf=CN=group2,OU=Atlassian,DC=NNNN,DC=com)
    ...
    (memberOf=CN=groupN,OU=Atlassian,DC=NNNN,DC=com)
  )
)
```

But, have to remember to reconfigure Crowd for every change in AD. IS there a better "catch-all" filter?

Comment: I'm not familiar with the product but can you use adfs to provide data on a per user basis?  that's far simpler than effectively trying to sync AD to the app.

Comment: LDAP searches against properties that contain distinguished names cannot be wildcarded. Can you modify your user provisioning process so there is one group that all Atlassian users belong to? This group would control the sync but not grant any access within the app.